# Creating a derived columns based on other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create derived columns from the actual dataframe which looks like below. I have a table with continuous medications and the timings of meds are recorded in the following way. Now, I am trying to create two new columns which record only when the medication was started and when it was ended. The actual dataframe looks quite big and the below dataframe is just a sample of original dataframe.

**EDIT:**

**EDIT 2:**

```
   DATETIME_1            DATETIME_2        DRUG
 2018-11-13 07:00:00  2018-11-13 07:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-13 08:00:00  2018-11-13 08:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-13 09:00:00  2018-11-13 09:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-13 10:00:00  2018-11-13 10:59:59  Drug 2
 2018-11-13 11:00:00  2018-11-13 11:59:59  Drug 2
 2018-11-13 12:00:00  2018-11-13 12:59:59  Drug 2
 2018-11-13 13:00:00  2018-11-13 13:59:59  Drug 3
 2018-11-15 07:00:00  2018-11-15 07:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-15 08:00:00  2018-11-15 08:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-15 09:00:00  2018-11-15 09:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-25 15:00:00  2018-11-25 15:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-25 16:00:00  2018-11-25 16:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-25 22:00:00  2018-11-25 22:59:59  Drug 4
 2018-11-25 23:00:00  2018-11-25 23:59:59  Drug 4
```

Expected DF:

```
     DATETIME_1            DATETIME_2      DRUG   START_TIME      END_TIME
 2018-11-13 07:00:00  2018-11-13 07:59:59  Drug 1 2018-11-13 07:00:00
 2018-11-13 08:00:00  2018-11-13 08:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-13 09:00:00  2018-11-13 09:59:59  Drug 1               2018-11-13 09:59:59
 2018-11-13 10:00:00  2018-11-13 10:59:59  Drug 2 2018-11-13 10:00:00
 2018-11-13 11:00:00  2018-11-13 11:59:59  Drug 2
 2018-11-13 12:00:00  2018-11-13 12:59:59  Drug 2               2018-11-13 12:59:59
 2018-11-13 13:00:00  2018-11-13 13:59:59  Drug 3 2018-11-13 13:00:00 2018-11-13 13:59:59
 2018-11-15 07:00:00  2018-11-15 07:59:59  Drug 1 2018-11-15 07:00:00
 2018-11-15 08:00:00  2018-11-15 08:59:59  Drug 1
 2018-11-15 09:00:00  2018-11-15 09:59:59  Drug 1               2018-11-15 09:59:59
 2018-11-25 15:00:00  2018-11-25 15:59:59  Drug 1 2018-11-25 15:00:00
 2018-11-25 16:00:00  2018-11-25 16:59:59  Drug 1               2018-11-25 16:59:59
 2018-11-25 22:00:00  2018-11-25 22:59:59  Drug 4 2018-11-25 22:00:00
 2018-11-25 23:00:00  2018-11-25 23:59:59  Drug 4               2018-11-25 23:59:59
```

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem and I'd really appreciate if I can get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `idxmax` and `idxmin`

```
s=df.DRUG.ne(df.DRUG.shift()).cumsum()
t=df.DATETIME_1.dt.date
s1=df.groupby([s,t]).DATETIME_1.idxmin()
s2=df.groupby([s,t]).DATETIME_2.idxmax()
df['start']=df.loc[s1,'DATETIME_1']
df['end']=df.loc[s2,'DATETIME_2']
```

Comment: I just edited the post. Most of the times the same drug is repeated after certain days and the same drug will be continued for a couple of days.

Comment: The previous code is working absolutely fine and it is my fault not to mention another scenario. Sometimes we have a Drug 1 administered on a day and after a couple of days, the same drug with different dosage will be administered.

Comment: @akashbachu what is the problem with me answer make you keeping accept and unaccept  ? ?

Comment: @akashbachu also update the answer again, and keeping edit the question is not recommended . Thanks

Comment: Oh!! I’m not doing that!! I’m not sure if there’s a bug in stackoverflow but whenever I refresh the page, it’s getting rid of the like.

Comment: You've been really helpful to me and I see that you answered most of my questions. I really appreciate that :)

Comment: @akashbachu happy coding